# How to increase element opacity incrementally as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm working on a svelte project and I'm trying to increase the opacity of a logo as user scrolls down...
what is the best method to achieve this?

I haven't tried much to this solution..

Comment: Is it about the logo coming into view or what exactly is the reason why it should increase opacity?

Comment: Yes making the logo visible by incrementally increasing the opacity as the user scrolls

Answer (score 0):

For viewport based interactions, you can use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), e.g.

```html
<script>
    function fade(node) {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            entries => node.style.opacity = entries[0].intersectionRatio,
            { threshold: new Array(101).fill(0).map((x, i) => i / 100) },
        );

        observer.observe(node);

        return {
            destroy: () => observer.unobserve(node),
        };
    }
</script>

{#each { length: 5 } as _, i}
    <div use:fade>
        Element {i}
    </div>
{/each}

<style>
    div {
        background: lightgreen;
        margin: 16px;
        height: 300px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    div + div {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/350099f08f614eb187f5531843338018?version=3.55.1)

Comment: can you explain how your solution works?

Comment: It just sets the opacity to the percentage of the element that is visible. Please read the documentation I linked to. `use:fade` is an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action).